# Input peripherals (mouse, keyboard, joystick) not working after windows update

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, windows-update

Yesterday when I restarted my computer I had to restart with "restart and update" (thanks MS for the choice...).

When restarting and the windows start logo disappear, every light indicator on all input devices go dark - and I end up at a login screen without mouse or keyboard working.

I tried fail safe mode, but same here.

I ended up reinstalling windows (from the recovery state), and after reinstall - everything works. Until I restart the computer and everything goes dark again...

Also when windows enter hibernation mode and wakes from that state, the usb devices doesn't seem to wake with the rest of the computer.

I've tried disabling power management on all USB devices, to no avail.
I've also tried setting the power button to "shutdown" instead of "hibernate".

Nothing seems to do the trick. Now everytime my computer restart I have to reinstall windows. I think I've reinstalled windows ten times by now.

Something seems to be broken with the latest windows update (as everything worked fine until last update), https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3172985.

According to the changelist, usb drivers seem to be part of the update (http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/4/0/A4079844-45E4-4531-ADB8-F3F28079A166/3172985.csv)

Anyone else who've experienced similar problems? How do I fix this?

--

These are the main components:

**Motherboard**: ASUS ROG Maximus VIII Impact (Socket 1151)

**CPU**: Intel i7 6700K Skylake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I solved the problem. I'm writing the answer here in case some other poor bastard has the same problem.

**All** USB-drivers **except** the one for USB 3.1 were inactive. Turns out I had **one** single port on my computer where I could plug in keyboard and/or the mouse.

From there I could reactivate the drivers and everything started working again.

This is a really serious bug. Say someone has this problem but doesn't have a single port that work. Then you'll never get it to work. Microsoft should really adress this issue.

[Next to the red 'x' is an icon which is visible if the device is inactive.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWSuo.png)